# How to check if two elements in a String array are duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I have a list of user inputted names like this

```
String [] names = new String[x];
```

Then let's say they entered these names

```
names = {John, Bill, Sam, John, Joe, Bill};
```

How do I check for duplicates in this array?
and then how do I print out what names are duplicates??

I have this so far, but it is not working

```
boolean duplicatenames = false;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < names.length -1; j++) {

        if (names[i].equals(names[j])) {
            duplicatenames = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I think its just checking if there is a duplicate. but how I do I make it print out which names are duplicates?

For example:

> "There are duplicate names. These names are: John, Bill"

Comment: check this too :http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/06/3-ways-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-java.html

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the array, save the values to a map of frequencies, and then filter out only the keys that have more than a single occurrence. Java 8's streaming API allows for quite an elegant syntax to do so:

```
List<String> duplicates = 
        Arrays.stream(names)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                               Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I've heard OP's gasps and sighs even at my place.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. loop over the array and find the match. If found add that entry in a list.
2. Iterate over the list of duplicate element and print it.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? I understand the logic, but I just don't know how to put it into code. I just started a few weeks ago..

Comment: As so often: should multiple (3-fold, 4-fold,...n-fold) occurrences result in 2 or 3 or n-1 duplicates being reported? If not, is this algorithm correct? If not, how can it be fixed? - In the light of this, given arbitrary inputs (e.g. a zillion times "John"), is there a better algorithm?

Comment: @laune yes there are so many better algorithm. Soora has already provided a link. I guess I am a bit late to see this. I hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` to save duplicate names as they occur. Print them as you wish.

```
Set<String> duplicateNameSet = new HashSet<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < names.length -1; j++) {
      if (names[i].equals(names[j])) {
         duplicateNameSet.add(names[j])    
   }
if(duplicateNameSet.isEmpty())
    System.out.println( "There are duplicate names.");
else
    System.out.println( "There are duplicate names. These names are: "+duplicateNameSet);
```

Comment: There's no need to maintain `duplicateNames` - the information is readily available from `Set`.  And it should be used to control this println.

Comment: @laune: So, you are saying, duplicate names should be printed as they occur?

Comment: I was saying that there is no need for the variable `duplicateNames`, even when you want to suppress the final println when there are no duplicates.

Comment: Oh okay, got it. You are right, thanks. I will refactor my code.

Comment: You may want to count the number of `{` and `}` ... since they are not equal.

Comment: I think these are used to represent the array, actual name to be compared are inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Build a `Map` of name to counter. In order to have an updatable counter, use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Then print all map entries with a counter >= 2. If you use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), then values will be listed in the original order of first seen.

```
String[] names = {"John", "Bill", "Sam", "John", "Joe", "Bill", "John"};

Map<String, AtomicInteger> nameCount = new LinkedHashMap<>(names.length * 4 / 3 + 1);
for (String name : names) {
    AtomicInteger count = nameCount.get(name);
    if (count == null)
        nameCount.put(name, new AtomicInteger(1));
    else
        count.incrementAndGet();
}
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : nameCount.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    int count = entry.getValue().get();
    if (count > 1) {
        if (buf.length() == 0)
            buf.append("There are duplicate names. These names are: ");
        else
            buf.append(", ");
        buf.append(name);
        if (count > 2)
            buf.append(" (").append(count).append(" times)");
    }
}
if (buf.length() != 0)
    System.out.println(buf);
else
    System.out.println("There are no duplicate names.");
```

**Output**

```
There are duplicate names. These names are: John (3 times), Bill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = {"John","Doe","John","Doe","Hello"};

Set<String> duplicatesNames = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> testSet = new HashSet<String>();
for(String name : names){
    boolean check = testSet.add(name);
    if(!check){
        duplicatesNames.add(name);
    }
}
System.out.println("Duplicates names are " + duplicatesNames);
```